# select query taking longer time to return results

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-performance

My table definition

```
CREATE TABLE public.state
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  state character varying(50),
  district character varying(50),
  block character varying(50),
  panchayat character varying(50),
  village character varying(50),
  habitation character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT state_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.state
  OWNER TO postgres;


CREATE INDEX state_allx
  ON public.state
  USING btree
  (id, state COLLATE pg_catalog."default", district COLLATE pg_catalog."default", block COLLATE pg_catalog."default", panchayat COLLATE pg_catalog."default", village COLLATE pg_catalog."default", habitation COLLATE pg_catalog."default");


CREATE INDEX state_habitationx
  ON public.state
  USING btree
  (id, habitation COLLATE pg_catalog."default");


CREATE INDEX state_idx
  ON public.state
  USING btree
  (id);
```

There are 80359 rows in the table.

```
  select * from state;
```

The above select statement taking 5.8 seconds to return results.

```
Total query runtime: 5.8 secs
80359 rows retrieved.
```

Explain returning the following the result.

```
EXPLAIN select * from state;

"Seq Scan on state  (cost=0.00..1872.59 rows=80359 width=75)"
```

Detailed EXPLAIN

```
EXPLAIN  (analyze, buffers, format text) select * from state ;

"Seq Scan on state  (cost=0.00..1872.59 rows=80359 width=712) (actual time=0.022..13.700 rows=80359 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1069"
"Planning Time: 0.727 ms"
"Execution Time: 19.810 ms"
```

How to improve the performance the above query.

System

```
macBook - i7 processor, 16GB RAM.
```

Comment: One way to possibly improve performance is to not use `SELECT *` but only include the columns you specifically need. That reduces the bandwidth transit time. The query you have can't be optimized any further because there are no conditions on it. What technology are you using to run the query? Maybe something there can be optimized to fetch the records faster.

Comment: Also, is this a locally hosted database or are you calling out to a hosted server somewhere? How much faster do you want the query to run?

Comment: @SamM Using in my localhost, expecting little faster below 2 seconds. I am executing the query in PgAdmin.

Comment: Since it's localhost on an i7 CPU and 16GB RAM I too would expect better performance. It might be worth your time to cross post to dba.stackexchange.com and see if that community can also provide some insights. I unfortunately don't have any further suggestions I can give. Hopefully someone else will speak up.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated the question with explain (analyze, buffers, format text)

Answer (score 1):

The query takes 19 milliseconds, which is a reasonable time given that the data are cached.

There are several explanations for the 5.8 seconds, which were probably measured on the client:

- The data were not cached in the original run (but that cannot fully explain such a long run time).
- The network between client and server is really lame.
- The client (pgAdmin?) takes a long time to render the result set.